# Method to program a large exceptions list

Tags: asp.net, architecture

I need to program a 15,000 item list that has different rules for each item. I need to make some sort of massive if statement or case. I was wondering if anyone knows a good way to seperate the rules file so that I can have a separate team build it and update it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Would be nice, if you provided some sample code to estimate complexity. Also as per description 'architecture' tag seems nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You may separate the rules in functions (15,000 rule functions) then you can group the rules in different files. Like this:

In file1:

- function condition1(){}
- function condition2(){}
- function condition3(){}

In file2:

- function condition4(){}
- function condition5(){}
- function condition6(){}

etc.